# Uncompilable code - cannot find symbol: method builder() location: class com.google.firebase.messaging.Notification

Tags: java, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm trying to send a notification from my Java web app to Android using FCM, but I'm getting an error:

> Uncompilable code - cannot find symbol   symbol:   method builder()
> location: class com.google.firebase.messaging.Notification

My full code:

```
public class FirebaseMessagingSnippets {
    
    public final static String registrationToken = "token";
    public final static String API_URL_FCM = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    public static void sendAll() throws FirebaseMessagingException, FileNotFoundException, IOException{
      
        //System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));

    FileInputStream serviceAccount =
      new FileInputStream("service.json");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
      .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
      .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    Message messages = Message.builder()
            .setNotification(Notification.builder()
                .setTitle("Price drop")
                .setBody("2% off all books")
                .build())
                .putData("title", "850")
                .putData("body", "2:45")
                .setToken(registrationToken)
                .build();
       // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    // registration token.
    String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(messages);
    // Response is a message ID string.
    System.out.println("Successfully sent message: " + response);
    
  }
   
}
```

There's no issue with Message.builder(), only for Notification.builder().

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Notification noti=new Notification("Title","Body");
Message messages = Message.builder()
        .setNotification(noti)
            .setToken(registrationToken)
            .build();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).